# Doing inserts with zend 2's tableGateway

Tags: php, datatable, zend-framework2, table-data-gateway

I using zf2's tableGateway and I'm unsure of the design it leads to.

Here is the canonical example of how to use zf2's tableGateway to do an insert (this [from the docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html)):

```
public function saveAlbum(Album $album)
    {
        $data = array(
            'artist' => $album->artist,
            'title'  => $album->title,
        );

        $id = (int)$album->id;
        if ($id == 0) {
            $this->tableGateway->insert($data);
        } else {
            if ($this->getAlbum($id)) {
                $this->tableGateway->update($data, array('id' => $id));
            } else {
                throw new \Exception('Form id does not exist');
            }
        }
    }
```

But defining the $data array seems redundant because I already have an Album class that looks like this:

```
class Album
{
    public $id;
    public $artist;
    public $title;

    public function exchangeArray($data)
    {
        $this->id     = (isset($data['id'])) ? $data['id'] : null;
        $this->artist = (isset($data['artist'])) ? $data['artist'] : null;
        $this->title  = (isset($data['title'])) ? $data['title'] : null;
    }
}
```

In my own project I have a model with about 25 properties (a table with 25 columns). It seems redundant to have to define the class with 25 properties and than also write a $data array inside of the method of a class implementing tableGateway with an element for every one of those properites. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at my [QuickStart 101 Tutorial](https://github.com/manuakasam/ZF2_3_QuickStart_Rewrite).

Basically you could do:

```
saveAlbum(Album $albumObject) 
{
    $hydrator   = new ClassMethods(false);
    $albumArray = $hydrator->extract($albumObject);
    // v-- not too sure if that one-liner works; normal if() in case it doesn't
    isset($albumArray['id']) ? unset($albumArray['id']) :; 

    // insert into tablegateway
}
```

Comment: Heyyy that's nifty. I don't understand the last line though, why are you doing: isset($albumArray['id']) ? unset($albumArray['id']) :;

Comment: well, the ID field shouldn't be existant on the DATA to update or insert (since it's usually autoID). Therefore you remove it only when it's existing, which on a new object is not the case but for an edit-object it is.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use RowGateway http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.db.row-gateway.html

Briefly, I'd extend album class from \Zend\Db\RowGateway\AbstractRowGateway class.

```
<?php
namespace Module\Model;

use Zend\Db\RowGateway\AbstractRowGateway;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Sql;

class Album extends AbstractRowGateway
{
    protected $primaryKeyColumn = array( 'id' );
    protected $table = 'album';


    public function __construct( Adapter $adapter )
    {
        $this->sql = new Sql( $adapter, $this->table );
        $this->initialize();
    }

}
```

And then you can do like this

```
$album->title = "Some title";
$album->save();
```

Or

```
$album->populate( $dataArray )->save();
```