# Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods extract() returning a null array

Tags: php, zend-framework2, table-data-gateway

I previously [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23252934/doing-inserts-with-zend-2s-tablegateway) about how to efficiently do an insert\update with a tablegateway and was informed of `Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods` as in this code [from the docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html):

```
public function saveAlbum(Album $album)
{
    $data = array(
        'artist' => $album->artist,
        'title'  => $album->title,
    );

    $id = (int)$album->id;
    if ($id == 0) {
        $this->tableGateway->insert($data);
    } else {
        if ($this->getAlbum($id)) {
            $this->tableGateway->update($data, array('id' => $id));
        } else {
            throw new \Exception('Form id does not exist');
        }
    }
}
```

Could be replaced with this code:

```
saveAlbum(Album $album) 
{
    $hydrator   = new ClassMethods(false);
    $data = $hydrator->extract($album);
    ...
```

But I found when using `$hydrator->extract($album);` it returns an empty array, what could be the cause of this? I did a `var_dump()` on the `$album` object being passed into the function and its seems valid. Is there something else I have to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class methods hydrator assumes you have `getXXX()` methods for each property, but the class in your previous question does not. You might want to try the `Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ObjectProperty` hydrator instead, this should return an array using the public properties from the object.

Comment: Nice, does just what I want. I'll have to read up on strategies. There aren't any caveats to this are there? Using public properties and exchangeArray() in my model like they do in the quickstart docs seems like a good approach.